# I want to apply a overlay image on hover

Tags: css

But I am struggling.

Code I have for css is:

```
#gallery img {
width:700px;
height:213px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

So I thought ...

```
#gallery img:hover {
    width:700px;
    height:213px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:10000;
    background: transparent url(../images/imgOverlay-Zoom.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Would work, but it doesnt.

The image I am transparently overlaying on hover is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong.
I think I may have a corrupt css tag somewhere.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _"it does not work"_? Can you clearify that?

Comment: You're trying to show a `background-image` in the background *of* an `img`? What does the relevant html look like?

Comment: If the original image doesn't have some transparency, then the background-image isn't visible, because it's in the background... as one would expect. The other way around might work, but I haven't tested this. I mean having the original image as background-image and then setting the src attribute to ../images/imgOverlay-Zoom.png on hover.

Comment: I now have this fixed, have amended the code / answer accordingly. Essentially, as you pointed out I didnt have my layers in order. All fixed. Posted code. Will happily make a js fiddle if someone wants to see it working, but this is part of a larger script I have been working on, that uses js to pre-load the image, and on-click shows annotated image. Looks superb now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.
css:

```
#container { position:relative; width:700px; height:213px;}
    .image { position:absolute; width:700px; height:213px; z-index:0;}
    .overlay { background-image:none); position:absolute; width:700px; height:213px; z-index:1;}
    .overlay:hover { background: transparent url(images/imgOverlay-Zoom.png)no-repeat center center;}
```

html:

```
<div class="overlay" ></div>
<div class="image" ><img src="images/listing-page-with-gradient.png" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `#gallery` have a background image rather than having an image tag inside it... otherwise it'll be on top of the background. Then have another div inside it which has the `:hover` pseudo-class. If it still doesn't work, take out the word `transparent`.

Or you could not overlay the image and just swap the original image for the combined image?

Comment: Hmm,, I would like the overlay image. Obviously using z-index I thought it would work. Perhaps I need to clarify a container, will keep playing. I looked at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474198/on-hover-overlay-image-in-css so maybe able to cobble a better work around, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hello there
I think you misunderstood the mechanics of CSS:
The image itself is an object and the background specified goes behind it.
So you have to make the non transparent image the background and specify the transparent one in the src. However this won't suit your needs.
A workaround would with CSS would be troublesome, so i would suggest to swap the whole image with a css hover or javascript onMouseover or jQuery - get familliar with those since it's the proper way.

Comment: I havent misunderstood, I just didnt clarify a container, an overlay and the z-index correctly. I dont need js to do this, in fact I now have it working, using pure css. Thanks