# Overlay transparent image on hover using CSS

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser

I'm trying to overlay a transparent image on hover using CSS.

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474198/on-hover-overlay-image-in-css) but it doesn't work in IE7 or IE8. Would anyone know how to do this?

I'm trying to keep super-light so don't really want to use js or anything similar.

Thanks

Comment: Consists the transparant image of only one color?

Comment: Would you be able to post the mark-up you're working with? Perhaps share a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what you've tried?

Comment: You can see the effect here - http://www.nightlylabs.com/uploads/test.html . It works in FF, Chrome but not IE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I checked your link and came up with [**this solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/353/) based on that.

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="xy.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="hoverimage" src="xy_hover.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image { position: relative; width: 184px; height: 219px; }
.hoverimage { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: none; }
.image:hover .hoverimage { display: block; }
```

Should work in all browsers including IE8 and IE7. It won't work in IE6 because it only allows :hover on certain elements like links (`<a>`). If you want to support IE6, change `.image` to be an `<a>` instead of a `<div>` and give it `display: block;`.

Answer (score 1):

This still doesn't work on IE7/8 AFAIK, so I'm afraid this won't answer the question.

However, I have ended up on this page when I forget how to make this work using modern methods, so I'm placing the answer here for reference.

I've only been able to do this by placing the `img` within a container/wrapper div, as `img` elements won't accept psuedo-classes like `:after`.

```
<div class="container"><img src="http://placekitten.com/240/320" alt="icanhaz"></div>
```

Then the CSS is styled to provide a pseudo element on hover.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Here you may also use images, gradients, etc */
}
```

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lingo/2umaG/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Usually we recreate the image that is supposed to have a transparent overlay in the .png format. .Jpeg is a flat image format which doesn't support transparency.

the next step we take is to have something like this :

```
<div style="Background-Image:Url(BackgroundImage.Jpg);Width:500px;Height:500px" >
   <div style="Background-Image:Url(OverlayImage.Png);Width:50%;Height:50%" >
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the closest to how I could understand your question

Comment: Long shot here, but try to change <div class="image" ><img src="alig.jpg" /></div> to <div class="overlay:hover" ><img src="alig.jpg" /></div>

Comment: Same problem. Works in everything except IE.