# Background image on top (Using CSS)

Tags: css, background

I have this image that I want to display on top of my product images when you HOVER on them.

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/vz2oj.gif]

This is what i'm using:

```
.centerBoxContentsFeatured img:hover {
    background-image:url('http://i47.tinypic.com/vz2oj.gif');
    }
```

It does work but it's being display behind the product image instead of on top of it. I tried absolute positioning and z-index but nothing seems to work.

http://www.pazzle.co.uk - trying to apply on the images on the main page. <<

EDIT:

```
#featuredProducts.centerBoxWrapper {
   position: relative;
   }
#featuredProducts.centerBoxWrapper:hover:before {
    content: '';
    width: 187px;
    height: 179px;;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image:url('http://i47.tinypic.com/vz2oj.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a {
    display: block;   
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
a:hover:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image:url('http://i47.tinypic.com/vz2oj.gif');
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pzd3n/1/)

Use a pseudo element.

Comment: this is a better answer than mine, pseudo elements are really useful for this kind of thing!

Comment: Thank you sir, I almost got it working, please see my edit in the OP. The image only appears in one position regardless of the image being hovered??

Comment: I took a look at your website, look like you applied the styles the wrong element. I think you should apply them to `.centerBoxContentsFeatured`

Comment: @KaeruCT is correct, the `div` should be the wrapper around each individual image, so in this case `.centerBoxContentsFeatured`.

Comment: excellent, works brilliantly. Just one more thing that probably isn't possible but the overlaying image now blocks the link of the image behind it, is there a way to apply the link to the price image too?

Comment: Put `display: block` on the link wrapping the image, and apply all this code to it rather than the wrapping div. `.centerBoxContentsFeatured a {...}`, etc

Comment: the links are created dynamically, I think it's fine as it is not worth the time figuring out how I would do it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

It's doing exactly what it's supposed to do. It's a background, so it will appear behind the container's content.

What you have to do here is to overlay a div over the image you're hovering.
I think this is possible a with a pure CSS solution, but it might be easier with some JavaScript.

See this question: [on hover overlay image in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474198/on-hover-overlay-image-in-css)